# iOS 12.2 : CMMotionManager is blocking the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, ios12, cmmotionmanager

I have an issue with `CoreMotion` and the following code :

`let motionManager = CMMotionManager()`

It blocks my Mainthread for 4-5 seconds and I don't know why. The problem appears when I updated my iPhone XR to 12.2. It does not block the mainthread with a iPhone 6S on 12.1.3.

I think it may be a hardware problem or iOS version.

Thank you

Comment: I see no problem with iPhone XR on iOS 12.2... are you sure that is the actual part of your code which blocks the main thread?

Comment: @holex yes, when i comment the line, it does not freeze. Are you using xcode 10.2 ?

Comment: I'm and that line blocks literally nothing on iPhone XR with iOS 12.2 – it may be something else in your code which causes your issue.

Comment: I found some links from radar which is the same problem that I have : [https://openradar.appspot.com/46210367](https://openradar.appspot.com/46210367) and [https://openradar.appspot.com/45003816](https://openradar.appspot.com/45003816)

It only blocks when my phone is on debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreMotion is doing a lot on his own during init.
Move the initialisation do a different thread. 
Edit:

I can confirm the issue with 12.2 on a development iPhone Xs. No issue on a real used device. I see also violation warnings telling CoreMotion tries to access the Applicationstate from a background thread.

However moving the init to a separate thread fixes any UI hangs here. The init of coremotion still does take a while. I created a empty single view application project and changed the ViewController class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var motionManager: CMMotionManager?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.motionManager = CMMotionManager()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            }
        }
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

}
```

Without a separate thread, the red color remains. With a separate thread the color is instant yellow and finally green on the dev XS and instant green on my iPhone 8Plus.

Addition:
Interestingly, without XCode attached, the dev device has no issues.
Try to run your code without being connected to the Debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Helge but it seems that even in a thread, the init of a CMMotionManager() is executed in the mainThread.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, but threading helps here. Can you please verify your results with my recent edit?

Comment: Yes, the problem only appears for me on debug mode. See the comments in my original post, there are two radars on the issue. Thank you again for the confirmation